# Uniform continuous function is bounded by linear function: prove by contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis

> Assuming $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ be an uniform continuous function, prove $$\exists a,b\in \mathbb R^+ \quad \text{such that}\quad |f(x)|\le a|x|+b.$$

I know this question has be answered, but I want to ask if I can prove it by contradiction, that is assuming that
$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb R^+ \text{, there exists } x\in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } |f(x)| > a|x|+b$$
and derive a contradiction. For such $x$, there is a nbd of $x$ such that the equation holds, and I try to derive
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| > \text{something}
$$
for $y$ in the nbd of $x$. Unfortunately I failed :(

Comment: I don't think this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prove this directly just using the definition.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for $\varepsilon=1$, fix $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ |f(x)-f(y)|<1,
$$
for any $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

**Claim.** For any $x\in\mathbb R$, $|f(x)|\leq a|x| + b$, with $a=1/\delta$ and $b=|f(0)|+1$.

The inequality is simply verified for $x=0$.

Given some real number $x\neq0$, put $\alpha=x/|x|$ and fix $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $$(n-1)\delta \leq x <n\delta.$$

For each $0\leq k\leq n$, define
$$
x_k= \alpha\frac{|x|}{n}k.
$$
We have that $x_0=0$, $x_n=x$ and $|x_{k}-x_{k-1}|=|x|/n <\delta$, for any $1\leq k \leq n$. Consequently, using the triangle inequality,
$$
|f(x)| = |(f(x)-f(0))+f(0)| \leq |f(x)-f(0)| + |f(0)| = |f(x_n)-f(x_0)| + |f(0)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\right| + |f(0)| \leq  \sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| + |f(0)| < \sum_{k=1}^n 1 + |f(0)| = n + |f(0)|.
$$
Finally, remember that
$$
(n-1)\delta \leq |x| \Rightarrow n \leq \frac{|x|}{\delta} + 1,
$$
and adding this to the previous fact, we derive that
$$
|f(x)| \leq n+|f(0)| \leq \frac{|x|}{\delta} + (|f(0)|+1).
$$
Since $x\neq0$ was arbitrary, the claim is proved.